# Using VCR mechanics to record and play queries to SQL database

Tags: python, django

Is it a viable approach to allow recording SQL queries to a file and later loading these queries from the file to memory and playing queries by monkey patching the db driver?

I had employed this method in the past for recording http queries to external services with library [vcrpy](https://vcrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I don't see any obstacles in implementation. The question is, does it even make sense in terms of test speed improvement? Also, what inconsistencies or pitfalls in usage of such an approach might this cause?

Comment: "in terms of test speed improvement"? To... improve the speed of what exactly?

Comment: @AKX I have hundreds of integration tests that access test database. We are talking about django here and postgresql to be exactly. It takes more than half of hour to run, beside asyncronisation I was wondering if I could improve speed run by using vcr method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Keploy](https://github.com/keploy/keploy) for this. It uses VCR like mechanics to generate stubs for not just API calls but also databases, and incase of SQL they are also readable/editable.

We don't support python yet (there's Golang, Java and Typescript/Javascript) but are adding support for [eBPF based language agnostic version](https://github.com/keploy/keploy/issues/436).

Disclaimer: I'm one of the maintainers of Keploy.